# if the pushforward is zero on a connected manifold then the function is constant.

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, manifolds, connectedness

Let $F:M \to N$ be a smooth map between manifolds, and suppose $M$ is connected and that

$$F_*: T_pM \to T_{F(p)}N$$

is zero for every $p \in M$. Then $F$ is the constant map.

Here is mt attempt:

Let $q \in N$ with
$$F(p)=q.$$
I claim the set
$$A=\{x \in M : F(x)=q\}$$
is both open and closed in $M$. Clearly it is nonempty as $p \in A$. And by connectedness of $M$, this would force $A=M$ thus $F$ is constant on $M$. For closed let $x_0 \in M$ and $\{x_n\} \subset A$ with
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n=x_0.$$
As $x_n \in A$ for every $n$, $F(x_n)=q$ and by continuity of $F$, we have that
$$F(x_0)=q$$
forcing $x_0 \in A$ thus $A$ contains its limit points and is closed in $M$. To show $A \subset M$ is open, fix some $a \in A$ and let $\epsilon>0$ be given such that
$$B_\epsilon(a) \subset M.$$
as $M$ is connected, it is path connected thus if $z \in B_\epsilon(a)$, then define
$$g:[0,1] \to M$$
via
$$g(t):=F(zt+(1-t)a)$$
so that $g(0)=F(a), g(1)=F(z).$  and $g$ is a path. Then
$$g_*=F_*(zt+(1-t)a)(z-a)=0.$$
Thus $g_*(t)=0$ for $t \in [0,1]$ implying $g$ is constant thus
$$F(z)=g(1)=g(0)=F(a).$$
I.e., $B_\epsilon(a) \subset A$ and $A \subset M$ is open thus is all of $M$ and $F$ is thus constant on $M$.

For an exmaple of when connecedness is dropped, then it fails, consider
$$f: \Bbb{R} \setminus \{0\} \to \{-1,1\}$$
via
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1 & x>0\\
-1 & x<0
\end{cases}.$$
This function has zero derivative but is non constant. Furthermore the domain is a disconnected manifold.

**Added:** *I am a bit shaky on the showing $A$ is open in $M$ but certain my closed argument works just fine. If I am correct, an upvote or a "looks ok" comment will suffice, if I am incorrect somewhere point it out and give a hint as to how to fix it please, thanks in advance! Also I think my counterexample works just fine*

Comment: Typo: "Clearly it is nonempty as $F(p)\in A$". I think you mean $p\in A$.

Comment: sorry yes $p \in A$ as $F(p)=q$ @user10354138

Comment: Looks fine, but didn’t read in full detail. It really is better to distill the argument into its essentials. First, show for any locally constant map between topological space, if the domain is connected, then the map is constant. Then, show using the mean-value theorem that for a differentiable function from an open set in R^n to R^m, having zero derivative implies it is locally constant. Finally, upgrade to the manifold context: show $F_*=0$ implies for every chart $(U,\phi)$ on $M$ and $(V,\psi)$ on $N$, $\psi\circ F\circ\phi^{-1}$ has vanishing derivative, hence $F$ is locally constant

Comment: @peek-a-boo does my argument not work?

Comment: I did say it looks fine

Comment: Showing the set of $x \in M$ such that $F(x)=q$ is open and closed in $M$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo ahh ok youre just giving me an alternate method, i see, thanks!!

Comment: no, not an alternate method. I’m trying to get you to see what constitutes a ‘better presentation’. It’s the same method/ideas.

Comment: Anyway, for closed you can just use Hausdorff property on $N$ so $\{q\}$ is closed, hence $F^{-1}(q)$ is closed.

Comment: @user10354138 true but my method works as well right? But youre saying since $F$ is continuous pull backs of closed are closed and in Hausdorff space singletons are closed. right?

Comment: @ted shifrin any input?

Comment: First, $p$ was a dummy variable, so you have to pick a particular $p\in M$. Next, I would assume by now that we know that the continuous preimage of a closed set is closed. But third, and most important, without going to a coordinate chart, I don’t even know what it means to talk about  $B_r(a)\subset M$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I meant to say $p\in M$ and you’re right as the manifold isn’t necessary the reals it wouldn’t make sense to say a ball is contained in $M$? Right?

Comment: @TedShifrin Every manifold is metrisable.

Comment: @MoeKhaledBin-Lateef I’m well aware of that. But the OP is applying the chain rule in the setting of a literal straight line segment in a Euclidean ball. Oh, and $g$ is a path in $N$, not in $M$.

Comment: @TedShifrin can my argument be modified using charts to show my $A$ is open in $M$?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: @TedShifrin so you can use a path in  your chart, then compose with the chart map into M, then you have a path from a to one of its neighborhood point

Comment: So like this let $g:[0,1] \to V$ be a path where $(V,\phi)$ is a chart on $N$, then define $\phi^{-1} \circ g:[0,1] \to \phi(V) \subset \Bbb{R}^n$ via $F(tz+(1-t)a)$ if $a \in A$ is fixed, and $\epsilon>0$ is given and $z \in B_\epsilon(a)$ is arbitrary

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that there are two points in the image, and pick a function $f:N\to\mathbb R$ that takes different values at those two points. The function $f\circ F$ is then not constant, but the chain rule tells you that its differential is zero.

Comment: Too vague.. I wanted to make my argument work. Am I on the right track somewhat?

Answer (score 0):

If $F_{*}=0$ then its matrix representation is the zero matrix. Hence locally, the partial derivatives of $F$ vanish. Hence locally, $F$ is constant. Since the manifold is connected, $F$ is constant everywhere.

Comment: What matrix representation? Are you choosing coordinate charts on both manifolds?

Comment: @TedShifrin Jacobian. Yes. Thats the canonical matrix representation associated to a derivative.

Comment: @TedShifrin But that doesn't matter, ofcourse.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can generalize the "$A$ is open"'s argument to prove the entire statement. First of all lets fix an $x_0\in M$ and define $F(x_0)=q$, now we have only to prove that $F(x)=q\;\; \forall x\in M$.

By $M's$ connectedness there exists some smooth path $\phi(t)$ from $x_0$ to $x$  (i'd avoid using  $tx_0+(1-t)x$ because we're not allow to treat points like vectors in a generic smooth manifold), now the following path on $N$ $$\alpha(t):=F(\phi(t)),\;\; \alpha'(t)=D_{\phi(t)}F (\phi'(t))\stackrel{F_*=0}{=} 0 \;\; \forall t, $$ has zero speed, so for the The Existence and Uniqueness Theorem for Solutions to ODEs, $\alpha(t)$ must be the constant path hence $$F(x)=F(\phi(1))=\alpha(1)\equiv \alpha(0)=F(\phi(0))=F(x_0)=q. $$